# Custom video player on Facebook wall

Tags: facebook, flash, embed, facebook-wall

I want to allow my page users to embed my own video player (Flash) on his Facebook walls. In this page in head I have:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="[Page Title]" />
<meta property="og:type" content="movie" />
<meta property="og:url" content="[page url]" />
<meta property="og:image" content="[url to jpg file]" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="[site name]" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="[my facebook id]" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="640" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="385" />
<meta property="og:video" content="[url to swf] " />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
```

When I'm logged in to my old Facebook account, post a link to this page and click them, I don't get my player, but I'm redirected to my page. This same hapened in my friends' accounts.

The player work good only when I'm loged in to new account created for tests.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need one more metatag and that is [og:video:secure_url](http://ogp.me/#structured). This problem is happening with users that are trying to view the video from a secure page. Check to see if the 2 accounts from where is not working have enabled Secure Browsing in Account Settings -> Security.

Comment: Thanks. I configured https on my web serwer, added this metatag and this solved my problem.

Comment: No problem! Can you please set the question as answered if that is all?