# How to make widgets that show in facebook comments

Tags: facebook, widget, soundcloud

I wondered if anyone know how soundcloud has been able to create a widget that plays directly in posts and comments on facebook?

Is this done via a specific deal they made with facebook, or is there actually a way to create a widget display when a certain type of link is shared?

Any insight on how this works would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

read the FB documentation on open graph - `og:video` tag.

facebook allows to show SWF inside the posts/comments. So all you need is to create a flash player for your content.

Comment: Thank you - would you be able to provide a link. I struggle getting around on facebook docs.

Comment: here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113297/custom-video-player-on-facebook-wall